# Using BLAT service in GITLAB

Tags: smtp, gitlab, blat

We have a GITLAB setup and 
We want to send the output of a error file as a attachment and giving a proper message including in the body as a mail notification to the recipients using BLAT as a service. Using below code

`blat -subject "IP is not pingable" -body "please check the attachment for the error logs" -attach C:\Temp\error.txt -to santoshkumar.angadi@yahoo.com`

We want to send this from the GITLAB. But I am getting BLAT error log as :

**Error: Not a socket**  for a SMTP server. How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Specify an SMTP server with the `-server <address>`

See http://www.blat.net/syntax/server.html

Make sure it's one that `blat` can connect to.

As http://www.blat.net/?docs/readme.txt says: To use Blat you must have access to a SMTP server via TCP-IP

Comment: setting **blat -install smtp-out.mail.com santoshkumar.anadi@yahoo.com**   I am getting below error ** Error: Not a socket for a SMTP server**  Any idea why this error

Comment: `smtp-out.mail.com` is not a valid SMTP server. I tested with `telnet smtp-out.mail.com 25` and I got: `telnet: could not resolve smtp-out.mail.com/25: Name or service not known`

Comment: I am using like `blat -install telnet smtp-out.us.gmail.com santoshkumar.angadi@gmail.com`  I got the error as **couldnot resolve hostname telnet**

Comment: Your quick response will be appreciated.

Comment: `telnet` is not a hostname, Santosh.

Comment: Is this on a self-hosted GitLab instance or on gitlab.com?  If on a self-hosted instance, do you have an SMTP server?

Comment: Then how to use it. Blat -install smtp server email ID. But it is throwing me error as socket layer error.

Comment: If you don't have access to an SMTP server, blat won't work for you. As http://www.blat.net/?docs/readme.txt says: To use Blat you must have access to a
SMTP server via TCP-IP.

Comment: I have installed blat and blat is working fine from CMD. If I type just blat and press enter it is giving me option that how to use blat. But from Gitlab it is not working.

Comment: Can you get blat to send email from the command line?  I thought it was throwing a socket error?

Comment: Yes it is throwing me socket error. Just to confirm blat is installed properly I typed blat from CMD and it is giving me options that how to use blat, and then I tried to set my SMTP using blat -install it is throwing me socket error

Comment: You need to provide a valid SMTP server, to which BLAT can connect on port 25.